# is there a way to load css variables according to current environement?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I have a react project with "_variables.scss" file with many variables.
I need to change the variables value according to the current environment, ( for example
$global-primary-background is green in one environment, but needs to be red in other environment). is there any solution for this?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to do could be:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ __DEVMODE__: false }) //set it depending on your webpack logic
```

create different scss files, one for prod and one for dev, then in your index load different files depending on `__DEVMODE__`